# Getting reference to element being observed with MutationObserver

Tags: javascript, mutation-observers

I am using MutationObservers to watch changes happening to multiple DOM nodes (basically adding to their subtrees or removing the nodes overall).

The observer works fine because I am using `subtree` option. The only problem is that I cannot get reference to the parent element that has the mutation observer attached to

```
const mutationObserver = new MutationObserver(mutationRecords => {
  mutationRecords.forEach(mutationRecord => {
    const addedNodesLength = mutationRecord.addedNodes.length;
    for (let i = 0; i < addedNodesLength; i++) {
      const node: Element = mutationRecord.addedNodes[i];
      // I need to check the parent of node that is being observed
    }
  });
});
```

I searched MDN and I cannot find any reference if that's possible. Any idea if that can be done?

Comment: There's no way as you can see in the specification. Simply save the element in a variable.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`mutationRecord.target` gives you the parent element, at least according to  [this](https://davidwalsh.name/mutationobserver-api)

I have tested it only on Firefox but it seems to be working.

Comment: Works in chrome too

Comment: This is only true when only using childList alone. OP is using subtree, and the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationRecord) state the target `is the node whose children changed`. Here is a [fiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/upgezhyf/3/), where console shows you that mutation.target is indeed not the initial observed element.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
const observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutationsList, observer){
  for(let mutation of mutationsList){
    console.log(mutation.target);
  }
});
```